# Weird warning from fsolve

Tags: python, warnings

I write very simple code with fsolve. The equations are not complicated. one is `a*(1-a)` with known `"a"` parameter, and the other one `x*(1-x)`.

The code is:

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import math
def equations(p):
    x = p
    a=0.1
    return (a*(1.0-a), x*(1.0-x))

x =  fsolve(equations, 0.1)
print equations(x[0]), x[0]
```

Even though the code and equations are very simple, fsolve cannot solve the equation. To test it I use the answer as an initial value, but still, it gives me a warning. why?

this is its warning:

> /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/optimize/minpack.py:161: RuntimeWarning: The iteration is not making good progress, as measured by the 
>     improvement from the last ten iterations.
>     warnings.warn(msg, RuntimeWarning)
>   (0.09000000000000001, 0.090000000000000011) 0.1

Comment: You are trying to use fsolve in a way that does not work, and I think you want to use it for a purpose it is not meant to. `x*(1-x)` is no equation and in `a*(1-a)` there is nothing to do if `a` is known. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: I have lots of equations that depend on the initial condition we should solve the equations. some times both equations contain x, which we should find it. Sometimes just one of the equations contains x and the other equation contains parameters that are known.  maybe if I change the  return of the def from " return (a*(1.0-a), x*(1.0-x))" to " return (a*(1.0-a)-x*(1.0-x))" it will work better.

Comment: Yes, this code works. Note that `fsolve` can only solve one equation of the form `f(x) = 0`. It does not work with multiple equations. With your change you make it solve `0.09 - x * (1 - x) = 0`. Depending on the initial value you will get one of the two solutions.